# RSPerl compared to rpy2

Tags: perl, r

I've been told by my coworkers that rpy2 is a great tool to work with data that benefits from the back and forth between python and R. But I am a perl monger, so I wonder if RSPerl will be as wonderful as I've been told rpy2 to be.

The website was last updated in 2007...

Cheers

Comment: 2007? ...So, I'm guessing no.

Answer (score 5):

To me, the main difference is that things from Omegahat are exceedingly clever and far-sighted yet don't always build reliably. It's more of an R&D lab.

Rpy2 on the other hand has a dedicated and focussed core developer in Laurent.

[Disclaimer: I'm the Debian maintainer for RPy2 (and a few related things) and tried in vain to package RSPerl, RSPython, ... and a few other Omegahat pieces by Duncan.]

Comment: To whoever downvoted: Please leave a comment explaining your reasoning as drive-by downvoting is not very productive.

Answer (score 1):

Beside wonderful features in an interface between language X and R, continued support is of utmost importance.

RSPerl might have built at some point in time, but there is a non-negligible chance that it does not any longer. In your situation, Perl did not know major transformations over the last years, but R surely did.

[Disclaimer: I am quite involved in rpy2, and within its ~3 years of existence the code base has required several changes because of changes in R and Python - in fact, I am not yet completely out of the woods with Python 3]